# Day abbreviations in python asctime()

Tags: python, time

Does anybody know specifically how python's asctime() shortens day names? Ex) Mon, Tues, Weds, Thurs, Fri? Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just apply `asctime` seven times and find out for yourself?

Comment: Where have you seen Wednesday abbreviated to Weds?

Answer (score 3):

The asctime docs say:

> Convert a tuple or struct_time representing a time
>   as returned by gmtime() or localtime() to a 24-character string of the
>   following form: 'Sun Jun 20 23:21:05 1993'. If t is not provided, the
>   current time as returned by localtime() is used. Locale information is
>   not used by asctime().

Note (1) constant length of 24 characters implies that day name abbreviations and month name abbreviations would need to be constant length e.g. 3 (2) The answer is locale-independent and a glancing reference is made to the `time` module's inheritance from the C stdlib, so it can be safely presumed that the names being abbreviated are those used in U.S. English.

Why are you not also asking about the months?

In any case, you can check this for yourself. The following was performed in the (default) C locale. A skeptic might like to change to some non-English locale and repeat the experiment

```
>>> import time
>>> nowsecs = time.time()
>>> time.gmtime(nowsecs)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=17, tm_hour=22, tm_min=43, tm_sec=54, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=77, tm_isdst=0)
>>> day_secs = 24 * 60 * 60
>>> for d in range(7):
...     print time.asctime(time.gmtime(nowsecs + d * day_secs))
...
Sat Mar 17 22:43:54 2012
Sun Mar 18 22:43:54 2012
Mon Mar 19 22:43:54 2012
Tue Mar 20 22:43:54 2012
Wed Mar 21 22:43:54 2012
Thu Mar 22 22:43:54 2012
Fri Mar 23 22:43:54 2012
>>> month_secs = day_secs * 365 / 12
>>> for m in range(12):
...     print time.asctime(time.gmtime(nowsecs + m * month_secs))
...
Sat Mar 17 22:43:54 2012
Tue Apr 17 08:43:54 2012
Thu May 17 18:43:54 2012
Sun Jun 17 04:43:54 2012
Tue Jul 17 14:43:54 2012
Fri Aug 17 00:43:54 2012
Sun Sep 16 10:43:54 2012
Tue Oct 16 20:43:54 2012
Fri Nov 16 06:43:54 2012
Sun Dec 16 16:43:54 2012
Wed Jan 16 02:43:54 2013
Fri Feb 15 12:43:54 2013
>>>
```

Skeptics corner:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "French_France")
'French_France.1252'
>>> time.asctime(time.gmtime())
'Sat Mar 17 23:07:28 2012'
>>> time.strftime('%a %b', time.gmtime())
'sam. mars'
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

uses the %a format char

Comment: -1 Doesn't use `strftime` with `%a`; that would make it locale-dependant, which it is documented NOT to be. See my answer.